# How do you create and write to a temporary file in a webapp?

Tags: angular, file, serialization

I'm trying to figure out how to create a temporary file in a web app (in some temporary folder).

So far, I've only been able to find ways to create a file to download in a web app, but I don't want this file accessible from users.

How would I do so?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to simply store data to be used at another time by your web app. Assuming you're using Angular given your tag, if you'd like to serialize some data (say maybe, a JSON file), you can store your serialized content in the browser using the `window.localStorage` API. Technically this data *can* be accessed by a knowledgeable user. It is ultimately up to you to determine if it's too sensitive to be saved in the browser.

You have many options in the browser for persisting some form of state:

- Cookies
- Local Storage
- Session Storage
- IndexedDB
- App Cache (deprecated, not recommended)

Comment: Thank you! Yep I was hoping to write XML code to an SVG file and then read it in with an img src tag in HTML. This was because I am getting a byte[] response from an API that is actually XML code and my attempts to integrate it as SVG weren't working (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68477015/api-byte-response-to-xml-in-angular-js?noredirect=1#comment121020193_68477015)

Comment: Ah okay, I see what you're doing. It may also help to know that you can use something called a Data URI. It would allow you to deserialize your `byte[]` into an XML document (your SVG), and then base64 encoding it. You can use base64 encoded image/svg data in an `<img />` tag. That way, your `<img />` tag doesn't have to point to a file. See more here: https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/09-svg-data-uris/

Comment: How does one deserialize the byte[] into XML?

Comment: It would depend on how it was serialized on the server. There are many ways of serializing content, so you'd have to give more details on exactly what your server is doing (where does it retrieve the XML from and how is it packed into a request).

Comment: In my code, I have:  `const url = "http://localhost:8081/bruml/export/${params}"
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.umlImage = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
        console.log(this.umlImage);
      }, 3000);`
which is how it gets the byte array and sends it to my umlImage variable

Comment: Hm I am doing some research and it seems like most of the methods I'm finding require a String input, but since I'm using a Sanitizer, I can't use this.umlImage as a string or call toString on it

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer this more specific question, as knowing the content of the XML/UML file you are hosting and the headers sent by the server (like the `content-type`) would definitely help. I do recommend that you open another question more specifically geared towards serialization. Also, you do not have to "store" the data in a file necessarily. You can configure your headers from your server to allow the browser to cache this, so long as it's static content that wont be changing much. Then subsequent calls to the server would be delivered from your cache, making requests quicker.